# Many times I "forget" to give (deserved) upvotes, because I would have to scroll up again

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, voting, up-votes

I came across a great (long) Q, with great (long) answers, several bounties awarded, a pleasure to read.

From the tags, and the first few lines of the Q it was not clear to me, whether I would enjoy it, or even read till the end. (**¹**).

At the end of the Question, I knew I wanted to up-vote, but already seeing the first/next answer, and that it has >0 score, makes me continue scrolling down and continue my reading flow instead of scrolling up to up-vote the just-read question or answer.

So I arrive at the bottom of the page, have 5+ new browser-tabs open, and now have to curb my burning curiosity to go scrolling up several screens to hunt for 3 up-vote buttons.

Many times my curiosity wins, I read the next tabs, forget/postpone to up-vote, and next time my Firefox updates, I close the accumulated 400+ tabs, and thousands in rep are lost.

How can we fix this?

I see several options (perhaps with a choice in the user-settings):

1. Dynamically reposition the vote buttons to always be in view
2. Add an up-vote button also near the bottom right of the post
3. Add a Keyboard Shortcut for up-voting, (or document it better, if exists)

Option 1 might be doable with some simple CSS/JS, implemented on your side, but somebody might have already make a user-script for this?

Option 2 is the one I would prefer. To the left of the post-author tag at the bottom of the post you could easily add an up-vote button/indicator.

Option 3 I would also like, but that might be tricky to implement. "Which of the 2 answers currently partially visible on his screen does he want to up-vote?"

Note 1: I posted this on Meta.U&L, because I do most of my reading and voting here, but this applies to all SE sites, and as such I do not object to any mod moves.

Note 2: This could be seen as a "bug" in the user-experience, so I also [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) ed.

(1) It's a [Q](https://superuser.com/questions/1189222/cd-rom-subchannel-is-different-when-dumping-the-same-disc) about an aspect of CD Video-Game ripping on Windows10. (An interesting aspect, as it turns out, not not only applicable to video games)

I stumbled on this, because it was linked to from a [HNP Meta Q](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12241/481365)

Comment: Wrong Meta... Not an issue on U&L. And how hard is it really to go to the top of the page? Most browsers have a single action for that, typically <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts are already available. Enable them in [your preferences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

[image]

The help <kbd>?</kbd>:

[image]

Voting <kbd>v</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time for pointing these out to me. I was looking at the tool-tips for the vote buttons, hoping to see the keyboard shortcut mentioned.